# Как правильно импортировать объект в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Мой репозиторий имеет следующий вид:

```
root
|
|__ module
    |
    |__ __init__.
    |__ submodule
        |
        |__ __init__.py
        |__ main.py
        |__ secondary.py
```

Файл **main.py**:

```py
from module.submodule.secondary import TestClass

test_class = TestClass()
```

Файл **secondary.py**:

```py
class TestClass:
    pass
```

Все файлы ****init**.py** пустые (автоматически сгенерированы PyCharm Professional 2020.2).

Я вызываю из корня репозитория команду `python module/submodule/main.py` и получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module/submodule/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module.submodule.secondary import TestClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'
```

Почему это происходит? Как я могу, не изменяя строку импорта, избежать эту ошибку?

P.S. Если запускать main.py при помощи IDE, ошибки не возникает.
P.S.S. Используется версия Python 3.8

Comment: `from .secondary import TestClass`

Comment: @Вадим Откуда возникает описанная выше ошибка? Можно ли как-то избежать её, не меняя импорта?

Answer (score 1):

ошибка появляется потому что `import` ищет файлы не в `root` а в текущей категории то есть в `submodule`. импортировать надо так:

```
from secondary import TestClass
```